# Apache htaccess get subdomain and prepend it to path

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

this is my first question on ServerFault and I think I couldn't find a similar one.

To the point. I would like to achieve the following using my `.htaccess`.

```
subdomaina.example.com/stats/ -> subdomaina.example.com/subdomaina/stats/
subdomainb.example.com/stats/ -> subdomainb.example.com/subdomainb/stats/
subdomainc.example.com/stats/ -> subdomainc.example.com/subdomainc/stats/
```

Subdomaina,b,c and test.com need to be dynamic and not static.

I know that I should be using the `mod-rewrite` but I am a bit confused.

I quite unexperienced with apache and `.htaccess`, so any pointers, clues, and explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve problems like this, you should read and become familiar with the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/), especially the [mod_rewrite reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html).

This example is easy enough:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/stats/(.*) /%1/stats/$1 [R]
```

Comment: Yes I am reading atm. But I could not get this up 2 hours now. I am following a similar approach and trying to learn as fast as I can. Will keep this updated. Thank you very much

Comment: My current problem is how to match the path. eg as you mentioned `(.*)\.example\.com$` with `$` at the end will match all paths (example.com/test and example.com/stats). But I would only like to match stats and this is the part where I am stuck.

Comment: The RewriteCond only matches the host name, but the RewriteRule includes a second condition that matches only the `/stats` path.

Comment: Great. Yes it's more clear now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Good, glad to help.

Comment: I got it. I think though that on the rule the first slash should be ommited because it matches on the condidion. I think like so: `RewriteRule ^stats/(.*) /%1/stats/$1 [R]`